# How to dynamically create a footer with Itext in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, footer

I have a serious problem with my footer generator. It has the function to describe one specific word from the page (I think that is called a footnote).
This function doesn't quite work yet, anyways. The problem is that my footer can have 1, all the way to 20 or something lines. And in most cases, it is overlapping with the text.
Here is the code of my footer creator:

```
Font fontTimes = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, 
 Font.NORMAL);
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
 table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
 table.addCell("all the descriptions.");

 table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(document.leftMargin()), 
 table.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(document.bottomMargin()), 
 writer.getDirectContent());
```

The rest of the pages are just created with lists that contains paragraphs, they are just added in the document. And I use "onEndPage" to put the footer in every page.
Here is some of the code I use to create and write in the document:

```
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(caminhoDoc) + File.separator + nomeDocumento + ".pdf"));
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            document.setMargins(36, 36, 36, 55);
            document.setMarginMirroring(false);
            writer.setPageEvent(this);

//creating lists...

            document.add(mainList);
```

The pdf is great, except the footer, that is overlapping the rest of the content. I am not sure how to fix it, I'm thinking that maybe the solution is to calculate the space that the footer will need, then set the specific page size to fit with that blank space for the footer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129084/itext-html-header-and-footer-dimensions
please refer to this link, might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small code sample to add footer dynamically to each page of the pdf using the PdfPageEventHelper interface

```
  package com.asu.util;

  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Date;

  import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

  import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
  import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
  import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
  import com.itextpdf.text.html.WebColors;
  import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
  import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
  import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
  import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
  import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


  public class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
/** Alternating phrase for the header. */
Phrase[] header = new Phrase[2];

/** Current page number (will be reset for every chapter). */
int pagenumber;

private ServletContext context;

private String domainName;


private String createdDate;

    public HeaderFooter(ServletContext context, String reportType, String             
    createdDate, String domainName) {
    this.context = context;
    this.reportType = reportType;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.domainName = domainName;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}




/**
 * Adds  the footer.
 * 
 * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,
 *      com.itextpdf.text.Document)
 */
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    Image image;
    Font fontStyle = new Font();
    fontStyle.setColor(255, 255, 255);
    fontStyle.setSize(6);
    try {

        image = Image.getInstance(context.getRealPath("template//images//footer1.png"));
        int indentation = 0;
        float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - indentation) / image.getWidth()) * 100;
        image.scalePercent(scaler);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        document.add(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
            new Phrase(String.format("Page - %d, Printed on : %s %s", pagenumber, date,
                    domainName), fontStyle),
            (document.getPageSize().getWidth()) / 2, document.bottomMargin() - 28.5f, 0);
}
  }
```

Then call the headerfooter onEndPage() from the pdf generation method

```
    HeaderFooter headerFooter = new HeaderFooter(context, "reportType", 
                                           reportCreatedDate, domainName);
```